# FCM Push notifications not popping up

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to show push notifications from device to device. For e.g. when user1 follows user2 I want user2 to get the notification across the top of their screen that user1 followed them. But right now the push notifications only works if I send it through a campaign from the firebase console. I've been looking through here for 2 days now and have no luck. Can someone please help me.

ProfileFragment:

```
private void addNotifications() {
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(profileid);

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("date_time", getTimeDate());
    hashMap.put("userid", firebaseUser.getUid());
    hashMap.put("text", "started following you.");
    hashMap.put("postid", "");
    hashMap.put("isSeen", false);
    hashMap.put("ispost", false);

    databaseReference.push().setValue(hashMap);

    // Retrieve the FCM registration token for the recipient user
    DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(profileid);
    userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                String fcmToken = dataSnapshot.child("device_token").getValue(String.class);
                if (fcmToken != null) {
                    // Send the push notification
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Snapshot: " + fcmToken, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if (!fcmToken.isEmpty()) {

                        sendNotification(fcmToken, "New Notification", "You have a new notification.");
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Token is null.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No snapshot found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Handle error
        }
    });
}

private void sendNotification(String receiverToken, String title, String message) {
    // Create the message
    RemoteMessage notificationMessage = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        notificationMessage = new RemoteMessage.Builder(receiverToken)
                .setMessageId(Integer.toString(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt())) // Unique message ID
                .addData("title", title)
                .addData("message", message)
                .build();
    }

    if (receiverToken.isEmpty()) {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Token is empty 2.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Token is not empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    // Send the message using FirebaseMessaging
    try {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(notificationMessage);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Notification sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("Notification", "Notification sent successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Notification failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.e("Notification", "Error sending notification: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "FCM";
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "mystro_push_channelID_900192"; // Replace with your channel ID

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // Handle the received notification

    Log.d("TAG96", "In here call 1");

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        // Generate a unique notification ID
        int notificationId = getNotificationId();

        // Build the notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mystro_logo)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        // Display the notification
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
    }
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
    // Handle token refresh or registration
    Log.d("TAG21", "New FCM token: " + token);
    // TODO: Send the updated token to your server or perform any other necessary actions
}

private int getNotificationId() {
    // Generate a unique ID based on the current timestamp
    return (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "Your Channel Name"; // Replace with your channel name
        String description = "Your Channel Description"; // Replace with your channel description
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    createNotificationChannel();

    Log.d("TAG96", "In here call");
}
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.mystro.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mystro.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyStro"
    tools:targetApi="m">
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/notification_channel_id" />
    <activity
        android:name=".EULA_Activity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".UserEmailActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".OptionsActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PrivacyPolicyActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TermsActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".BioEditActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FullnameActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".UsernameActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ChangePassword"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity android:name=".EditProfileActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ChatActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CommentsActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ForgotPasswordScreen"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FollowersActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I don't see the issue at first glance, but if you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).

Comment: @AlexMamo hello. I'm using Java not kotlin.